# All my project in android studio gives error saying startup failed when opened

Tags: android-studio

[image]

when i open any of my problem in android studio i am welcomed with this error.

```
startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Tormentor\build.gradle': 18: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 18, column 1.
this began to occur when my computer shut down in the middle of a gradle build please help me/

startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Tormentor\build.gradle': 18: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 18, column 1.
```

Comment: try to use `invalidate caches/restart`

Answer (score 0):

You somehow managed to copy a null-byte-character into your source code. Try to open the file in another editor and resave the file. That might help.

Thanks.